# solving $u_t = u_{xx} +2u_x +u+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have this problem :  $$u_t = u_{xx} +2u_x +u+1$$
with boundaries of $$0<x<1$$  $$   0<t$$
and  we also have $$ u(x,0) = x$$
$$u_x (0,t) = sin t$$ $$ u(1,t) + u_x(1,t) =2$$

I need to solve this problem but I have no idea about the way I can use the last condition. can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Make the boundary conditions homogeneous by letting $u(x, t) = v(x, t) + \tilde{u}(x, t)$ and fixing $\tilde{u}$ so that $v_{x}(0, t) = v(1, t) + v_{x}(1, t) = 0$. Then use separation of variables.

Comment: @mattos I don't know how to do this, can you please help me more?

Comment: I would actually start with introducing $v(x,t)=u(x,t)+1$ to get rid of that $1$ in the equation. Then use separation of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $e^x$ we arrive at
\begin{align}
(e^x(u+1))_t=(e^x(u+1))_{xx}.
\end{align}
Taking $e^x(u+1)=w$ we arrive at the heat equation
\begin{align}
w_t=w_{xx}.
\end{align}
Can you solve it from here?